# Ошибка при создании SQL-функции для вычисления суммы заказа

Tags: sql, база-данных, функции

В проекте есть три таблицы (заказ, состоит_из и артикль). Пытаюсь вычислить общую сумму заказа и вернуть это значение через функцию для последующего применения. Следующий код работает и выдает общую сумму заказа:

```
    select sum(Sub.LineItemSum) as gesamtsumme from (
select besteht_aus.ArtikelID, ArtikelAnzahl*Artikel.Preis as LineItemSum
From besteht_aus inner join Artikel
where besteht_aus.ArtikelID = Artikel.ArtikelID and BestellID = 2) Sub
```

Но если я пытаюсь засунуть этот кусок кода в функцию, получаю ошибку.

```
create or replace function gesamtsumme (@BestellID integer)
returns money
begin
    declare @summe money
    set @summe = (select sum(Sub.LineItemSum) as insgesamt from ( select besteht_aus.ArtikelID, ArtikelAnzahl*Artikel.Preis as LineItemSum
From besteht_aus inner join Artikel
where besteht_aus.ArtikelID = Artikel.ArtikelID and BestellID = @BestellID) Sub) 

return @summe
end
```

Подозреваю, что set просто не справляется с подзапросом. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как её исправить.

Comment: вы получаете просто слово "ошибка", или таки текст какой-то имеется?

Comment: Попробуйте: `return (select sum(Sub.LineItemSum) ...)`

Comment: подозреваю что в конце операторов нужны точки с запятой. вы СУБД не указали и дилаекты у всех разные но в хранимых процедурах у большинства точки с запятой нужны. И да, set обычно не справляется с запросами. обычно используется что то вроде `select ... into переменная` или `select переменная:=sum ....` если это вдруг MySQL

Comment: Это что за диалект SQL, в котором при внутреннем соединении двух таблиц нет необходимости указывать условие соединения?

Comment: SQL Anywhere. Select = пробовал, select into нет, в итоге обошёлся "костылём" - просто создал процедуру, которая показывает эти данные. К первому комментарию: Sybase Central ругался на ошибку в set. Сильно не ругайте, только учусь, вопрос задавал во время подготовки студенческого проекта.